# Codeigniter localhost CSS

Tags: css, codeigniter, localhost

I've crawled forums far and wide for a solution for this, but to no avail.

I'm running an app on a localhost and I want to link to my CSS styles in my html page.

The general consensus is that I should use `base_url() . "css/main.css"` to create a link.

The PROBLEM lies in the fact that I want other people on my network to be able to use my app. But when they link to my page from their computer, they see

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/codeigniter/css/main.css
```

which of course does not load the CSS to the page, as the css files are on my localhost, not theirs.

Please tell me there's an elegant solution to this problem. Codeigniter is driving me kind of nuts.

Comment: in fact this question applies to all links i would include in my document!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

modify the $config["base_url"] value to the IP address assigned to your computer. Like:

```
$config["base_url"] = "http://192.168.1.5/codeigniter/";
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need here is to setup base url as per ENVIRONMENT

```
switch(ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'localhost':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/codeigniter/whatever/';
        break;
    case 'anothercomputer':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://anotherdomain.com/';
        break;
    default: //live
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomain.com/';
}
```

obviously you'll need to setup ENVIRONMENT const to all these values by checking e.g. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] etc in the `index.php`

Answer (score -1):

There is 3 Ways of adding css style to your document most common way is external,
use this code to get style from external file.css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your_css_file_location.css" />
```

the css file should be at .css format,
another way is by using internal, the style tag goes between the  tags ,

```
 <style type="text/css"> your style here </style>
```

and last the inline,

```
<body style="background-color: #FF0000;">
```

hope you got this, have a nice day.

Comment: The problem isn't regarding how to import a style, the problem is to have the right absolute path for sharing across the network.

Comment: I am sorry Apparently did not understand the question correctly